# Where can I find my windows phone 8 apps isolated storage on my computer?

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I'm developing a windows phone 8 app and I am writing in some files. Sometimes I want to open thees file in a new file explorer to see their content, not read them from c# code. Any idea where can I find a IsolatedStoargeFolder or something?

The isolated storage explorer tool did not helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use File Explorer to navigate Isolated Storage unfortunately.

The Windows Phone Power Tools work well as an alternative, although they don't currently work with 8.1 Emulators http://wptools.codeplex.com/

Comment: Well, what can I say ... It's pretty useful since I use WP 8.0. I'm using .xml files so I have to "download" them and the view. And I los all day trying to solve the problem. Anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [IsoStoreSpy](https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/). A cool place to view your Isolated Storage files on both WP 8.0 and WP 8.1 device/emulator. Check it out.